# What is the OLY used behind the names of Olympians?

Tags: olympics, international-sports

Many Olympians used the OLY behind their names on their social media, business cards and other settings.

It clears why they can use the OLY, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

According to a [post on the World Olympians Association](https://olympians.org/news/983/oly-post-nominal-letters-to-honour-olympians/):

> Much like a doctor, a lawyer or a university professor, becoming an Olympian takes many years of hard work and requires a diverse range of skills. I believe this initiative will provide Olympians with the professional recognition they deserve.

The iniciative is to give ongoing recognition of the work that was put into becoming an Olympian and then also the continuation of upholding the Olympic values.

See the video on [What is OLY](https://youtu.be/NgRQ3yCa6SE) from the World Olympians Association for more information.

[image: OLY lapel badge from Tokyo 2020]